# Grant Permission to a User who belongs to a Role which Denies Permission on that same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a fixed set of SQL User Groups, where all of our staff are added into. We have assigned a custom db role "**db_RestrictedAccessToConfigs**" to all of our fixed set of SQL User Groups. We have then assigned Role Permissions on this db role "**db_RestrictedAccessToConfigs**", such that INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE Permissions are DENIED on a fixed set of Configuration Tables.

We now have a requirement that certain users need to be able to edit (Insert, Update & Delete) one or two of these Config Tables, for a short amount of time (say 3 days). How do I GRANT these users INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE Permission without compromising the DENY Restrictions that we put on the the rest of the group in the db role "**db_RestrictedAccessToConfigs**".

I learned that DENY trumps GRANT. So even if I give Role Permission to this user i.e. GRANT permission to INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE, then it will re-direct it to DENY permission set of the db role "**db_RestrictedAccessToConfigs**".

Comment: Create a new role with less restrictions. Revoke the first role and grant the new one. Use the "script as" feature of SQL Server Manager to create a script of the existing role.

Comment: That won't help, right? Because my ask is "How do I GRANT these small set of users (say 1 or 2 people) INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE Permission without compromising the DENY Restrictions on the majority of people in the existing role?"

Comment: The short answer is you can't do that. Hence, add a new role and "move" the user "temporarily" (notice - the burden is on you to enforce that time constraint).

Comment: Thanks Smor. So when you say "move", you mean "remove" the user from the old role and "add" them to the new role. Once the user is done with their work, I would have to "move" them again, from the new role to the old role. Did I interpret your solution correctly? Is there any other solution? Also, I super appreciate your answer (I did know about this one but wanted to know if there's a better way).

Comment: One question that I'd have about the current setup is: how (specifically) does a given individual currently have the db_RestrictedAccessToConfigs role applied to them? Does everyone have their own login/user in the database? Are they part of an AD group? How permissions will need to be apportioned depends (in part) on that.

Comment: Currently, all users login through their own credentials but we have created logins for their AD Groups (not individual login/user). There are about 6 AD groups and all except one are assigned that role of db_RestrictedAccessToConfigs. The one AD group is db_owner. So plan was to create a new AD group (7th), add the special users to this AD group, grant Insert/update/delete permission to this AD group. But since the user is also already assigned to that old AD group, which has db_restrict..., which has DENY permission, hence gives permission error